# plt scatter not showing same points as imshow with same data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, scatter

I am trying to overlay points and values that show up fine on a scatterplot, into an image. I have an image of size (1200,1920,3), and a list of points organized as (x,y,value) that I call uv, of size (3,16425). When I show these points on a scatterplot, they show up as I want them to. However, when I try showing these points in an array of size (1200,1920) and then displaying using imshow, not only do most of the points not show up, but the dimensions are also backwards. I don't know what's going on, as it is the same data in both cases. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
uv_new = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
max_depth = np.max((uv[2,:]).astype(np.float64)) # just a normalizer
uv_int = uv.astype(int) # Since I'm putting it in an array, I need integer x,y coordinates
print(img.shape)
x = (uv_int[0]/np.max(uv_int[0])*(img.shape[0]-1)).astype(int) # Normalize x coordinates
y = (uv_int[1]/np.max(uv_int[1])*(img.shape[1]-1)).astype(int) # Normalize y coordinates
z = 1-uv[2]/max_depth # The color values I want to show
uv_new[x,y] = z # Set the image I want to show with the color values
plt.imshow(uv_new,origin='lower') # Show this image which should contain all the points, but doesn't
print(np.count_nonzero(uv_new)) 
print(np.count_nonzero(z)) # Comparing these two just to show that no data is lost
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
#plt.imshow(img)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
scat = plt.scatter(x,y, c=z, s=1, cmap=cm) # What I want, but is different from the image above, even though it is the exact same data
#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

EDIT:
As per the most recent comment on the answer, here is the updated results switching so that uv_new is now of shape (img.shape[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWlYT.png),img.shape[0]), and moving to uv_new[y,x] = z.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have, I believe, a few mistakes in your snippet.

- You do not need `uv_int` because when you calculate x and y, you cast them as integers with `astype(int)`.
- The reason why `count_nonzero` returns two different values is probably that you get some duplicate coordinates (x, y) for multiple non-zero values of z when you perform the normalization. Applying the previous point might help in discarding a few duplicates.
- This call `uv_new[x,y] = z` is the reason why your `imshow` plot is transposed. Yes, `x` represents the X axis and `y` the Y axis, but keep in mind that in terms of displaying matrices, (rows, cols) is actually equivalent to (y, x). So please update your call to `uv_new[y, x] = z` and change the shape of `uv_new`.
- Use the same colormap for each plot. Please avoid using jet or rainbow as well. Matplotlib has viridis, inferno, magma, plasma and cividis which are great colormaps you should use. Just add the keyword `cmap='plasma'` in both calls to `imshow` and `scatter` for example.

EDIT:
Here is an actual example with randomly-generated data. The first two plots are similar to what you do, except that the `interpolation` keyword for `imshow` is used. The last plot is similar to the second one but the background color is changed so as to try to match the first plot and the size of the scatter dots is decreased. See how first and last image resemble each other? I think this roughly explains why you do not get the same plots with imshow and scatter. Snippet and figure below (figure quality is pretty poor due to the size restriction, so please execute the snippet on your machine to get a better quality image).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
uv = rng.random(size=(3, 16425))
uv_new = np.zeros((1920, 1200))
x = (uv[0] / np.amax(uv[0]) * (uv_new.shape[1] - 1)).astype(int)
y = (uv[1] / np.amax(uv[1]) * (uv_new.shape[0] - 1)).astype(int)
z = 1 - uv[2] / np.amax(uv[2])
uv_new[y, x] = z
fig, (ax, bx, cx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, num=0, figsize=(20, 10))
ax.imshow(uv_new, origin='lower', cmap='plasma', interpolation='bilinear')
bx.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=1, cmap='plasma')
cx.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=0.02, cmap='plasma')
cx.set_facecolor('xkcd:royal blue')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
bx.set_aspect('equal')
bx.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
cx.set_aspect('equal')
cx.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('/home/thomas/so.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. If I change the axes, then I get a bounding error (out of bounds) when I'm writing to the empty array. I'm not sure why this would be the case, since I'm normalizing the X by image.size[0] and y by image.size[1]. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you also need to change your first line: `uv_new = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))`.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, and that fixes the sideways problem, but I still have the problem of the points shown being much fewer than in the scatter plot.

Comment: Do you mind updating the figures attached to your question with the new results?